# How to correctly import solders for Pubkey into a project?

Tags: python, solana, solana-program-library

I am trying to write a script in Python to track events from the solana blockchain. I read that solana public key is now used as solders pubkey.

this is my code:

```
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solana.rpc.websocket_api import connect
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.transaction import Transaction
```

I have already installed

```
pip install solders solana
```

but I keep and continue to have this error

[image]

> import "solders.pubkey" could not be resolved from source Pylance

which is making my code fail as I can not retrieve the progam_id as a pubkey

I have tried to reinstall the dependencies to make sure the dependencies were installed correctly

I have already tried in different environments to isolate the problem, but somehow the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys looks like it was only a VSC problem displaying an error expecting a py doc for solders package but its a rust compilation.

Should work fine regardless